# How can i get root category id w.r.t store in header.phtml

Tags: magento2

How can i get root category id w.r.t store in header.phtml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code to your phtml file:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->create('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$rootCategoryId = $storeManager->getStore($storeManager->getStore()->getId())->getRootCategoryId();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override Header.php file and add construct function like -

```
protected $storeManagerInterface;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $StoreManagerInterface)
    {
         $this->storeManagerInterface = $StoreManagerInterface;
    }

public function getRootCategoryId()
    {
        $storeID       = $this->storeManagerInterface->getStore()->getId();
        return $this->storeManagerInterface->getStore($storeID)->getRootCategoryId();
    }
```

Then in header.phtml use like

```
echo $block->getRootCategoryId();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface class to get store default root category Id.

```
<?php 
class Test{

protected $storeManagerInterface;

public function __construct(\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $StoreManagerInterface)
{
     $this->storeManagerInterface = $StoreManagerInterface;
}



public function getRootCategoryId()
{
    $store = 1;
    return $this->storeManagerInterface->getStore($store)->getRootCategoryId();
}}
```